# How to make QVideoProbe work?

Tags: android, c++, qt, camera, qml

I'm currently making a cross-platform app (Android, iOS) using QML, and I need to do a QR code scanning function. The QR code readings are using ZXing and there is no problem, the problem is on the camera. **I can't extract video frames from QCamera**.

There is a module `QVideoProbe` which is supposed to do it for me. However, it doesn't work
, not on Win32, not on OSX. It simply doesn't work on desktop platform. I don't have my code on this computer, but it's just like this example I found on the forum

```
QCamera *camera = new QCamera;
camera->setCaptureMode(QCamera::CaptureVideo);
QCameraViewfinder *viewfinder = new QCameraViewfinder();
camera->setViewfinder(viewfinder);
qDebug() << " start set source";
QVideoProbe *videoProbe = new QVideoProbe(this);
if (videoProbe->setSource((QMediaObject *)camera)) {
    qDebug() << " set source succeed";
    //Probing succeeded, videoProbe->isValid() should be true.
    connect(videoProbe, SIGNAL(videoFrameProbed(const QVideoFrame &)),this,SLOT(detectAVA(const QVideoFrame &)));
}
camera->start();
```

The guy on the forum has the same problem with me. The line:

```
videoProbe->setSource((QMediaObject *)camera)
```

will return `false`.

The reply on the forum is:

> Using (passing) a `Camera` element as sourceObj, what will happen?
>
> It will also work.
>
> That was in theory. In practice, it depends on the platform.
>   `QVideoProbe` is not available on all of them (or only for either a
>   media player or a camera).
>
> It should be in the doc, but here's an overview of `QVideoProbe`
>   support:
>
> - Android: only for camera
> - Blackberry: no support
> - iOS: no support
> - Linux: only for media player
> - Mac: no support
> - Windows: only for media player
>
> If it’s not supported it doesn't necessarily mean it's not possible to
>   do it on a given platform, it can mean that it’s not currently
>   implemented.
>
> So, Android is only platform that support for Camera, then I am
>   looking for support on Win32, I am willing to add support under win32,
>   is that work will be really hard, and I will merge it into Qt
>   mainline.
>
> Besides, I will add media player support under Android. That’s two
>   feature I am looking for.

Looks like it's not implemented, and if this works, it will only work on Android, and I have to test it on a real phone (simulator doesn't work).

I guess extracting a frame from camera is a very basic function on any platform and language. There must be a way. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I implemented this using a hack. It works somewhat as expected. The idea is to use `QAbstractVideoSurface` as a makeshift alternative to `QVideoProbe`. It has many drawbacks, but at least it is something.

Code below compiles but I honestly don't know if it works (it has been sitting dormant for a while). Use at your own risk!

**PoorMansProbe.hpp**

```
#ifndef POORMANSPROBE_HPP
#define POORMANSPROBE_HPP

#include <QAbstractVideoSurface>
#include <QList>

class QCamera;
class QCameraViewfinder;

class PoorMansProbe : public QAbstractVideoSurface
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QCamera *source;
public:
    explicit PoorMansProbe(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat> supportedPixelFormats(QAbstractVideoBuffer::HandleType handleType) const;

    // Called from QAbstractVideoSurface whenever a new frame is present
    bool present(const QVideoFrame &frame) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

    bool setSource(QCamera *source);

    bool isActive() const;


signals:
    // Users of this class will get frames via this signal
    void videoFrameProbed(const QVideoFrame &videoFrame);
    void flush();

};

#endif // POORMANSPROBE_HPP
```

**PoorMansProbe.cpp**

```
#include "PoorMansProbe.hpp"

#include <QVideoFrame>
#include <QCamera>
#include <QCameraViewfinder>


PoorMansProbe::PoorMansProbe(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractVideoSurface(parent)
    , source(0)
{
}

QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat> PoorMansProbe::supportedPixelFormats(QAbstractVideoBuffer::HandleType handleType) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(handleType);
    return QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat>()
           << QVideoFrame::Format_ARGB32
           << QVideoFrame::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied
           << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB32
           << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB24
           << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB565
           << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB555
           << QVideoFrame::Format_ARGB8565_Premultiplied
           << QVideoFrame::Format_BGRA32
           << QVideoFrame::Format_BGRA32_Premultiplied
           << QVideoFrame::Format_BGR32
           << QVideoFrame::Format_BGR24
           << QVideoFrame::Format_BGR565
           << QVideoFrame::Format_BGR555
           << QVideoFrame::Format_BGRA5658_Premultiplied
           << QVideoFrame::Format_AYUV444
           << QVideoFrame::Format_AYUV444_Premultiplied
           << QVideoFrame::Format_YUV444
           << QVideoFrame::Format_YUV420P
           << QVideoFrame::Format_YV12
           << QVideoFrame::Format_UYVY
           << QVideoFrame::Format_YUYV
           << QVideoFrame::Format_NV12
           << QVideoFrame::Format_NV21
           << QVideoFrame::Format_IMC1
           << QVideoFrame::Format_IMC2
           << QVideoFrame::Format_IMC3
           << QVideoFrame::Format_IMC4
           << QVideoFrame::Format_Y8
           << QVideoFrame::Format_Y16
           << QVideoFrame::Format_Jpeg
           << QVideoFrame::Format_CameraRaw
           << QVideoFrame::Format_AdobeDng;
}

bool PoorMansProbe::present(const QVideoFrame &frame)
{
    if (frame.isValid()) {
        emit videoFrameProbed(frame);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool PoorMansProbe::setSource(QCamera *source)
{
    this->source=source;
    source->setViewfinder(this);
    QCameraViewfinderSettings viewfinderSettings;
    // I have a broken camera that only support these settings, but you should put whatever settings you need here
    viewfinderSettings.setResolution(640, 480);
    viewfinderSettings.setMinimumFrameRate(0.0);
    viewfinderSettings.setMaximumFrameRate(30.0);
    source->setViewfinderSettings(viewfinderSettings);
    return true;
}


bool PoorMansProbe::isActive() const
{
    return (0!=source);
}
```

Comment: This solution works very well on windows, but do not work on android(Qt5.9.1)

Comment: @StereoMatching I developed this for Linux (Ubuntu) so at least it used to work there.

Comment: Thank you so much! After a week of my futile attempts I finally came across your post and you saved me :). Just a funny little project for Ubuntu Touch I wanted to give a try but without your solution I would have had to give up.